# Qt - Static Linking fail after so many attempts

Tags: qt, static, compilation

I've been trying to do a static linking for Qt for several weeks but I just keep on failing. I followed alot of articles and steps but none of them worked out for me. I downloaded the latest Qt SDK and the msvc2010 library for the command prompt. What am I doing wrong?

In my Qt Creator, my compiler is set to release msvc2010 and I did "configure -platform win32-msvc2010" in the Qt Command Prompt and then the nmake. But that didn't work. I set it to MingW and tried, but still failed. Please help me! If you need any information, just ask for it.

Comment: Can you give me any link or ideas on how I can build my own static Qt Libraries from the source?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Qt source from their website.
2. configure it by `configure -static`
3. Then compile it using nmake